# Three.js r125 BufferGeometry `vertices` does not exist

Tags: three.js

I'm working on updating Three.js and I find that when I upgrade to r125, attempts to set `vertices` on BufferGeometry fail due to the method missing. It also appears to have removed `verticesNeedUpdate`. The [migration guide](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#r124--r125) does not appear to warn about this and the [changelog](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases/tag/r125) doesn't seem to address it from what I can see.

I unfortunately didn't write the original code so I'm unsure of how to resolve it. The code looks like this:

```js
this.geometry.vertices[0].x = this.geometry.vertices[2].x = -this.canvas.width / 2;
this.geometry.vertices[1].x = this.geometry.vertices[3].x = this.canvas.width / 2;
this.geometry.vertices[0].y = this.geometry.vertices[1].y = this.canvas.height / 2;
this.geometry.vertices[2].y = this.geometry.vertices[3].y = -this.canvas.height / 2;
this.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

#### Update using Don's Answer Below

After applying Don's suggested change, we wind up with this:

```js
    const negativeWidth = -this.canvas.width / 2;
    const positiveWidth = this.canvas.width / 2;
    const positiveHeight = this.canvas.height / 2;
    const negativeHeight = -this.canvas.height / 2;

    this.geometry.attributes.position.setXY(0, negativeWidth, positiveHeight);
    this.geometry.attributes.position.setXY(1, positiveWidth, positiveHeight);
    this.geometry.attributes.position.setXY(2, negativeWidth, negativeHeight);
    this.geometry.attributes.position.setXY(3, positiveWidth, negativeHeight);
    this.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first changelog entry for three.js r125 is the relevant one:

> Geometry has been removed from the core. It is now located in `examples/jsm/deprecated/Geometry.js`.

The `THREE.Geometry` class has been been deprecated for a while, but some older code and examples outside of the project repository still refer to it. The recommended replacement is [THREE.BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry), which is more performant. The `BufferGeometry` class does not have a `.vertices` property, so that's probably the cause of the particular error you're seeing. Instead, you can update vertices like this:

```js
geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ( index, x, y, z );
geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I'm updating my question to include the modern version of the code. Thank you!

Comment: I was tearing my hair out trying to locate this - Thank you so much!