# three.js — faceVertexUvs is undefined on version r.133

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use a function to assign UVs with three.js and it worked great on revision r.103.
Unfortunately I can't manage to make it work on r.133

Here's my function :

```
assignUVs(geometry) {

    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = [];

    geometry.faces.forEach(function(face) {

        var components = ['x', 'y', 'z'].sort(function(a, b) {
            return Math.abs(face.normal[a]) > Math.abs(face.normal[b]);
        });

        var v1 = geometry.vertices[face.a];
        var v2 = geometry.vertices[face.b];
        var v3 = geometry.vertices[face.c];

        geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push([
            new THREE.Vector2(v1[components[0]], v1[components[1]]),
            new THREE.Vector2(v2[components[0]], v2[components[1]]),
            new THREE.Vector2(v3[components[0]], v3[components[1]])
        ]);

    });

    geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

I've the following error `Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')` related to this line of code : `geometry.faceVertexUvs[0] = []`

I tried to convert my Geometry into a BufferGeometry (using `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeVertices`) but it didn't change a thing. It's like the faceVertexUvs attribute doesn't exist anymore.

Here's a codepen with my code : https://codepen.io/michaelgrc/pen/ExvbMWP

Does anyone know what I'm missing ? Thanks a lot

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874065/three-js-r125-buffergeometry-vertices-does-not-exist

Comment: This issue has an explanation here: [Three.js r125 BufferGeometry \`vertices\` does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66874065/three-js-r125-buffergeometry-vertices-does-not-exist). In essence, the legacy `Geometry` was removed from the core in `r125` so `r133` is now using the new `BufferGeometry` approach. For more info, you can [read this Three.js forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/three-geometry-will-be-removed-from-core-with-r125/22401).